# Order years and quarters in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(time = c("T2/2023", "T1/2023", "T4/2022", "T3/2022", 
"T2/2022", "T1/2022"), PIB = c(73050L, 71798L, 68247L, 68652L, 
67968L, 65843L), `Valor afegit brut` = c(67426L, 66399L, 64218L, 
63228L, 62436L, 60339L), Agricultura = c(756L, 689L, 384L, 404L, 
405L, 429L), Indústria = c(13281L, 13172L, 12710L, 12715L, 12557L, 
12204L), Construcció = c(3112L, 3030L, 2872L, 2832L, 2788L, 
2736L), Serveis = c(50277L, 49508L, 48252L, 47276L, 46686L, 44970L
), `Comerç, transport i hostaleria` = c(17737L, 17301L, 16455L, 
16009L, 15959L, 15007L), `Act. immobiliàries, professionals i altres` = c(22085L, 
21974L, 21768L, 21269L, 20820L, 20210L), `Adm. pública, educació, sanitat i serveis socials` = c(10455L, 
10233L, 10030L, 9998L, 9908L, 9753L), `Impostos nets sobre productes` = c(5624L, 
5399L, 4028L, 5424L, 5532L, 5504L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000223e08b4ae0>)
```

And I need to order column `time`. To that matter, T1/2020: `T1` indicates first quarter, and so on and so forth, and 2020 the year.

How can I order this column so that `time` is ordered from past to present observations?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, you could convert it to a year/quarter format (here, using `zoo::as.yearqtr()` since it supports a format option) then arrange:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(zoo::as.yearqtr(df$time, format = "T%q/%Y")) %>% 
  arrange(time)

# or this approach, if you dont want to modify the format 
df %>% arrange(zoo::as.yearqtr(df$time, format = "T%q/%Y"))

# Printing just the `time` column to demonstrate

#     time
# 1 T1/2022
# 2 T2/2022
# 3 T3/2022
# 4 T4/2022
# 5 T1/2023
# 6 T2/2023
```

A more generalized approach (ie, if they weren't representative of time formats) is to separate them out into two separate columns using `tidy::separate_wider_delim` (with `cols_remove = FALSE`), then using `dplyr::arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

separate_wider_delim(df, time, names = c("quarter", "year"), 
                     delim = "/", cols_remove = FALSE) %>%
  arrange(year, quarter)
```

This gives you (only printing relevant columns for space considerations):

```
#   quarter year  time   
#   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  
# 1 T1      2022  2022/T1
# 2 T2      2022  2022/T2
# 3 T3      2022  2022/T3
# 4 T4      2022  2022/T4
# 5 T1      2023  2023/T1
# 6 T2      2023  2023/T2
```

If you wanted to delete the newly created columns, just simply add the following at the end of the pipe: `... %>% select(-c(quarter, year))`, or if you want to keep them but have `time` remain in the first column, add `... %>% relocate(time)`.

Comment: Is there any way that I can place column `time` back to the first column?

Comment: If you delete the columns using `... %>% select(-c(quarter, year))` then `time` will be first by default. If you want to keep the new columns, you can do `... %>% relocate(time)` instead, which will manually place `time` first

Comment: Is it possible to consider `time` as in Date format? Because I need to plot `PIB` and `time`

Comment: Add `... %>% mutate(time = zoo::as.yearqtr(df$time, format = "T%q/%Y"))` to the end of the pipe

Answer (score 1):

Use of `substr` and `substring`.

```
> dat[with(dat, order(substr(time, 1, 2), substring(time, 4))), ]
     time   PIB Valor afegit brut Agricultura Indústria Construcció Serveis  ...
6 T1/2022 65843             60339         429     12204        2736   44970  ...
2 T1/2023 71798             66399         689     13172        3030   49508  ...  
5 T2/2022 67968             62436         405     12557        2788   46686  ...
1 T2/2023 73050             67426         756     13281        3112   50277  ...
4 T3/2022 68652             63228         404     12715        2832   47276  ...
3 T4/2022 68247             64218         384     12710        2872   48252  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can do

```
data$time <- sub(pattern = "^T([1-4])/(\\d{4}$)",
 replacement = "\\2Q\\1", x = data$time)
```

to get it in a more standard format. If you sort by time: `setorder(data, cols = "time")`, string sorting should do the job.

But you could then also use `lubridate::yq(data$time)` to turn it into dates. Then the command above would also sort correctly.

Comment: Hi @backboned - great advice here, but for this to be complete answer you'd need to demonstrate how to sort the data table by the newly modified `time` column. At the moment, your code essentially only provides information on how to change the string format from `yyy/qq` to  `yyyQq` - this is not an answer to the question, but one step along the way. A more complete answer would likely get you more upvotes. Just trying to help as I see you're relatively new to this forum and want to encourage your contributions. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have added it.